# akka http: Akka streams vs actors to build a rest service

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

When it comes to creating a REST web service with 60+ API on akka http. How can I choose whether I should go with akka streams or akka actors?
In his [post](http://www.smartjava.org/content/building-rest-service-scala-akka-http-akka-streams-and-reactive-mongo/), Jos shows two ways to create an API on akka http but he doesn't show when I should select one over the other.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a difficult question. Obviously, both approaches work. So to a certain degree it is a matter of taste/familiarity. So everything following now is just my personal opinion.

When possible, I prefer using akka-stream due to its more high-level nature and type safety. But whether this is a viable approach depends very much on the task of the REST API.

#### Akka-stream

If your REST API is a service that e.g. answers questions based on external data (e.g. a currency exchange rate API), it is preferable to implement it using akka-stream.

Another example where akka-stream would be preferable would be some kind of database frontend where the task of the REST API is to parse query parameters, translate them into a DB query, execute the query and translate the result according to the content-type requested by the user. In both cases, the data flow maps easily to akka-stream primitives.

#### Actors

An example where using actors would be preferable might be if your API allows querying and updating a number of persistent actors on a cluster. In that case either a pure actor-based solution or a mixed solution (parsing query parameters and translating results using akka-stream, do the rest using actors) might be preferable.

Another example where an actor-based solution might be preferable would be if you have a REST API for long-running requests (e.g. websockets), and want to deploy the processing pipeline of the REST API itself on a cluster. I don't think something like this is currently possible *at all* using akka-stream.

#### Summary

So to summarize: look at the data flow of each API and see if it maps cleanly to the primitives offered by akka-stream. If this is the case, implement it using akka-stream. Otherwise, implement using actors or a mixed solution.

Comment: Thanks Rüdiger for the clear answer. What I don't like about mixing both is that to have back-pressure you need to rely on publisher/subscriber model to your actors. Which forces you to rely heavily on `ask` pattern rather than `tell` if you want to send your request down the actor hierarchy. An actor per request pattern is valuable considering the trivial cost of new actor. I also see stream work very well as an aggregator to the underlying sub-rest services to group sub-APIs easily. This is specially important when you develop for mobile where # request should be minimal. What do you think?

Comment: To be honest, I try to use akka-stream as much as possible and only use raw actors when I have special deployment or other needs. I think a large number of use cases map pretty well to akka-stream.

Comment: Excellent!  BTW could you provide a simple use case of the sentence "actors would be preferable might be if your API allows querying and updating a number of persistent actors on a cluster."

Answer (score 11):

### Don't Forget Futures!

One addendum I would make to Rudiger Klaehn's fine answer is to also consider the use case of a [`Future`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future).  The composability of Futures and resource management of `ExecutionContext` make Futures ideal for many, if not most, situations.

There is an excellent [blog post](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html) describing when Futures are a better choice than Actors.  Further, the back-pressure provided by Streams comes with some pretty hefty [overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416891/akka-stream-implementation-slower-than-single-threaded-implementation).

Just because you're down the rabbit hole using akka-http does not mean all concurrency within your request handler has to be confined to Actors or Streams.

**Route**

`Route` inherently accomodates Futures in the [type definition](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/index.html#Route=akka.http.scaladsl.server.RequestContext=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[akka.http.scaladsl.server.RouteResult]):

```
type Route = (RequestContext) ⇒ Future[RouteResult]
```

Therefore you can bake a Future directly into your Route using only functions and Futures, no Directives:

```
val requestHandler : RequestContext => HttpResponse = ???

val route : Route = 
  (requestContext) => Future(requestHandler(requestContext)) map RouteResult.Complete
```

**onComplete Directive**

The [`onComplete`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/server/Directives.html#onComplete[T](future:=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[T]):akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directive1[scala.util.Try[T]]) Directive allows you to "unwrap" a Future within your Route:

```
val route = 
  get {

    val future : Future[HttpResponse] = ???

    onComplete(future) {
      case Success(httpResponse) => complete(httpResponse)
      case Failure(exception)    => complete(InternalServerError -> exception.toString)
    }
  }
```